# How to connect to a proxy server with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-scraping, web, puppeteer

I am trying now for a while to connect to a proxy with puppeteer. I am using the latest version and I couldn't get it to connect after endless tries. I searched, I documented, I read but I don't even know what to do anymore.

This is what I tried yet:

```
 browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            defaultViewport: null,
            args: ['--start-fullscreen', 'proxyServer=ip:port'],
        })
```

or instead of proxyServer I tried with "--proxy-server" but still does not work. Or I also tried doing it like this:

```
await browser!.createIncognitoBrowserContext({
            proxyServer: 'http://ip:port',
        })
```

Still nothing. Puppeteer version is 21.1.1
Also I am using proxies which do not need username and password so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add the args like this:

```
args: [
  '--start-fullscreen',
  `--proxy-server=http://${host}:${port}`
]
```

and to authenticate you would do:

```
await page.authenticate({ username, password })
```